# segmentation fault with assembler code

Tags: linux, assembly, 64-bit, fault

hi because my prof couldnt help me at all and told me to use a vm i wanted to ask u to help me. all programms i write in c are compiling well and running without errors. so i dont understand why i get the error: segmentation fault when i want to run a programm like this:

```
global main

extern printf

section .data
    message: db 'Hello, World', 10, 0   

section .text

main:  
    push message
call printf
add esp, 4
ret
```

im using the 64bit version of linux mint cinnamon 17.2
i hope u may can help me and thank you for answers

Comment: true thank u just needed a 32bit nasm but thank u anyway :)

Comment: got the answer: using 32 bit nasm and evrything works perfetct :)